# Track UserID who accessed/loaded this SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint, sharedpreferences, powerapps, power-automate, access-rights

onload SharePoint page, I want to track the page title and userID who accessed the SharePoint page.
I am looking for ways, how to implement it in Power Automate?

Please advise. I am new to the Power Automate world.

Answer (score 2):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-usage-data-for-your-sharepoint-site-2fa8ddc2-c4b3-4268-8d26-a772dc55779e

You can't automatically trigger flows when someone just opens a sharepoint page. You either use analytics or some type of custom javascript/other fancy coding tool. PowerAutomate won't work for this.

Comment: What if I change the onload to on click a hyperlink, do I still need custom javascript ?

Comment: When you click a hyperlink, you can trigger a PowerAutomate on HTTP request. Based on either the URL or the body, you can determine what page was clicked et cetera.